# Android N 7.0 status bar animation

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to implement the new Android N notification drawer into my app. I've managed to mimic the L and M themes already, but my question is

How is the expansion animation created? What type of view is there and how it reacts to swiping down? Below is a GIF so you can see what I mean. Is that a custom GridView? Or something more advanced?

[image: Android N status bar]

Thanks a lot for any thoughts on how this works.

Comment: look in the AOSP source code for the Settings/Notification status bar.

Comment: Yeah.. I've had a slight look but it's so complicated and there are so many dependencies and custom views.

Comment: Alex Newman,

I have a favor to ask.
When we slide the notification bar up/down there is an animation where one row goes below the other row and so on until the bar closes.

The req for me is a slide down menu with a list of rows and this animation (one row goes below the other on scroll)

Are you aware of any such libraries or code that could be helpful in implementing such animation.

If not did you manage to find solution for your question?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @VaseemSathar I did manage to find a solution. Looked in AOSP for it. I could eventually help you with your request as it's not much different and uses the same technique.

Comment: @AlexNewman Wow Thanks. That would be great

Comment: @VaseemSathar leave me your email either here or on your profile.

Comment: @AlexNewman Its vaseemsathar@gmail.com

Thank you:)